# How can you set a string array to an enum via config?

Tags: c#, config, .net-6.0, kestrel

In .net core configuration you cap use config options, which maps a section in the config to an object. For Kestrel this seems to happen automatically. The bit I'm interested particularly is the 'SslProtocols' where you can state the protocols required in a `string[]` like this:

```
"Kestrel": {
  "Endpoints": {
    "Https": {
      "Url": "https://localhost:5003",
      "SslProtocols": [ "Tls12", "Tls13" ]
    }
  }
}
```

If I wanted to create this manually using IOptions how could I map the SslProtocols string array to the enum? I've tried something like this:

```
"HttpsEndpoint": {
  "Url": "https://localhost:5003",
  "SslProtocols": [ "Tls12", "Tls13" ]
}
```

I then have an HttpsEndpointOptions object:

```
public sealed class HttpsEndpointOptions
{
    public Uri Url { get; init; } = new UriBuilder("http", "localhost", 5004).Uri;
    public SslProtocols SslProtocols { get; private set; } = SslProtocols.None;
}
```

I use `GetSection("HttpsEndpoint").Get<HttpsEndpointOptions>()` to map it, but the SslProtocols always remain as the default. So I imagine there's some mapping I need to do. However, I can't do this in the options object as that is created before the configuration is used. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: I don't think the configuration supports flag enums

Comment: Ok, so I guess I'll need some manual mapping to get the `string[]` into an enum.

Comment: it will get the individual values, but not the combined ones

Comment: Maybe store the Protocols as a simple string not as an array of string so it gets parseble? `"SslProtocols": "Tls12, Tls13"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like the configuration supports using commas as delimiters for flag enums. So I was able to use "Tls1, Tls2" for example. This converted to `SslProtocols.Tls1 | SslProtocols.Tls2`.